# When Rebuild Project at that time android studio giving error

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have just create new project and added jar files and just clicked on Rebuild Project from Build menu but it gives below error.

[image]

Comment: Is there any jar file missing or gradle issue, or any other configuration is missing?

Comment: when you click on it where does it send you?